How to explain large deposit into my account?
I wish to apply for a UK family visitor visa along with my family. I work as a bank employee and switched job a year ago. A large sum was deposited to my salary account as severance benefit by my previous employer which in turn I kept as Fixed Deposit with the same bank. Now for the purpose of UK visit I have encashed the FD and had the money returned to my previous salary account. How do I explain this and should I do this in the cover letter or write a separate explanation letter? I can provide trace of the money through statments of FD and salary accounts.

Voting to close. Since the explanation for the large deposit is given in the question there doesn’t seem to be an issue to resolve.

@Traveller, the issue is figuring out how to present the explanation in a clear and believable way.

@Mark What is the issue? ”I am funding my trip from the severance benefit of xxx from my previous employer, which I kept as Fixed Deposit before transferring the money to my salary account on dd/mm/yy.” Perfectly clear and believable, supported by the relevant paperwork. All as described in the question itself.

The easiest way to do this is to include statements from your FD account and salary account. Either give statements from before you were given the severance, or starting after the severance was transferred to the FD account (assuming that was more than six months ago). Provide notes tracing the path of the money if you wish, but the officer can probably track it themselves.
If the statements provided include the initial payment of severance into your salary account then include a note saying what it was. However if the payment was a year ago then it probably isn't going to be a problem.

Thanks! I'll include the note in my cover letter.
